# My virtual machine (Virtual Box) stop working, it does not accept a mouse nor my keyboard

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox, mouse, freeze

This issue is in **Oracle VirtualBox Manager with Ubuntu** at the latest update.
Two days ago, I turned on my virtual machine (connected to a public network), and it enters immediately to the desktop, skipping the user login, but I ignored it. After that, the VM did not capture my mouse.

I'm in the newest version of the VB, so I restart the Virtual Box, but it did not help.
I already disabled and enabled the mouse capture, I try with the physical keyboard and `soft keyboard`, but none of them are being captured by the machine or get an actual response.
I add more memory to the machine, changed the system's `pointing device` to the 3 options, and none of them works. I also try to drag a file from my windows desktop, and it's just stuck in the Ubuntu desktop however, it did not help at all.
I have to mention that since the last update, I kept getting the notification that there was an error, and if I wanted to report it, and I always marked "yes" anyways I did not worry about it:(

I don't want to lose all the files and information I have in my VM, so I'm trying to fix this. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: What does this mean: "I kept getting the notification that there was an error"

Comment: Just literally had this notification that said "There was one error found in your system, do you want to notify it?" and I always responded "yes". It never said where was the error or anything like that.